# Opera dynamic JavaScript execution fails

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dynamic, opera

I have a serverside generated JS file linked in my HTML head.

I use this, to be able to insert scripts dynamically from anywhere inside my PHP scripts to the head tag.

There is a global accessible object I can pass JS code, then it stores it in the session with a key, inserts the key to the HTML Frame template, then the browser loads the stored script by loading the dynamic script that outputs it from the session storage.

This works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and even in IE, but not in Opera.

In Opera, from about 10 reload attempts, only in 1 attempt the script gets executed.

Currently all of the dynamically generated JS code is inside a jQuery DOM Ready event. This may be related to the problem I think.

Loading the dynamic script with AJAX and evaluating it would surely solve this problem, but I want a clear HTML output, without direct scripts in the head. This way of loading and evaluating is impossible from a linked static script, as the template engine has to insert the session storage key of the script to the HTML frame template.

---EDIT---
Dynamic Script Output:

```
$(function(){
//Calls to some jQuery Plugins on class and id selectors (on some reloads getting executed, but mostly not)
});
```

DOM:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>            
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
<!-- CSS Links, Meta tags -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>           
<!--jQuery Plugins External Script tags-->
<script src="http://[MY_DOMAIN]/dynamic.js/[JS_STORAGE_KEY(MD5)]"></script>                                   
</head>
<body>
<!-- VALID HTML5 CODE -->
</body>
</html>
```

---EDIT 2---
I may have found the cause of the problem:
Opera requests external scripts more than once. See my last comment for more details.
By the way, if that's the case, it's very concerning regarding bandwidth usage too in certain circumstances and situations.

Comment: What's the question? You will need to show us the generated script code and the DOM you insert the script...

Comment: I don't feel like the problem is well represented by your post. I think you have some as of yet implementation specifics that contribute to this issue. Consider providing a *real*, working example, if possible. My opinion is that assuming no software bugs, recent opera's should not behave this way.

Comment: When Opera successfully executes the dynamic script (1 reload attempt from 10, only the dynamic key differs in the output), it works perfectly. The only thing I can think, is that there are multiple separate jQuery DOM Ready events. But I have never heard it can cause problems, and never experienced any until now.

EDIT: Just checked, and the dynamic script is not even in Dragonfly under the scripts tab... After this, even DOM Ready event may not be related with the problem.

Comment: Ok, it seems I've found the problem: Opera seems request the dynamic script more than once, and the script finally loaded is not from the first request.

This is a problem, since my framework deletes the JS Store entry from the session after the first request for garbage collection purposes (there is a remember me option which makes the session id cookie valid until 19 January 2038, and I don't want the session to be full of expired JS codes)

Comment: If you found a solution: you can (and should) write an answer to your own question. @ the problem: what cache headers did you set for that dynamicly generated script?

Comment: There was no cache headers specified, but now tried with this brutal one:
header ("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Connection: close");
Same results... And also, the url is always different, so there may be no caching even without cache control headers.

Comment: Just made a debug feature that counts how much time the same key is requested, and prints it out to the script output if the store is already empty. It shows 2...

And by the way I can't yet answer my own question as I don't yet have 10 rep.

Comment: That would be a pretty serious bug in opera. I can't reproduce it on 11.64

Comment: I've checked the network tab in Dragonfly, and it indeed requests every script twice. The server's default cache setting disables caching in every way. Now I sent a HTTP header manually enabling caching for 60 secs (as there is a very low chance there will be two identical random md5 hashes for two requests within one minute and one session), and it finally solved the problem, as the second request is now loaded from the browser cache, based on the first request that recieves the script properly.

Comment: This sounds pretty odd - I have no idea why Opera would do this. However, if you could send me some link or demo - if you wish to keep it more private you can use E-mail and contact me on hallvors at myopera.com - I could try to figure it out so that the underlying Opera bug can get fixed..

Comment: AFAIK - the problem with Opera is that it does not guarantee the order of execution of scripts in the head. It executes them by the order they get to the client. It could be that your script generator is faster then the cdn - especially if your working on localhost. I came to your post trying to find any news about this issue